# The best way to retrieve multi-records of range ids in one query in MySQL!

Tags: mysql

E.g:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM movie WHERE movie_id IN (1,4,6,7)
```

the `movie_id` is `primary key`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice...seems like you got it, what's your question?

Comment: I just want to check it is the right way to do this! Than you very body!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will `SELECT` all columns from the `movie` table where the `movie_id` is in the list.  It will return your 4 records.  Records 1, 4, 6 and 7.